# Radzen data grid dynamic data and values

Tags: datagrid, radzen

I am needing to be able to generate columns and values from dynamic data.  My model is a List that contains a string and another list.  The string is the column name, which I can get to display correctly.  The list however I have not been able to get working correctly.  I am getting one of three things all the time.  1) No values  2) The control name 3) The values but the values for each Column level item.

So with 3 columns and each column having 3 data point I can generate all three columns, but I get all three columns worth of data in each column.

Below is the code I am using for the data grid it's self as well as the code for adding the data to the outer and inner lists.

If anyone has any ideas of how to complete this I could really use the help at this point.

```
  public List<rdzTest> getData()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            rdzTest rt = new rdzTest();
            //rt.name = new List<string>();
            rt.name = "Property Name " + " -- " + i.ToString();
            rt.values = new List<string>();
            string s = "";// "<ul>";
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                //s += "<li>values " + j.ToString() + " Property -- " + i.ToString() + "</li>";    
                s = "values " + j.ToString() + " Property -- " + i.ToString();   
                rt.values.Add(s);            
            }
            //s += "</ul>";
            //rt.values = s;
            alpha.Add(rt);
            //alpha.name = rt.name;
            //alpha.values = rt.values;
        }
        return alpha;
    }
```

```
<RadzenDataGrid TItem="rdzTest" Col Data=@alpha>
    <Columns>        
        @foreach(rdzTest rt in alpha)
        {
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="rdzTest" Property=@rt.name Title="@rt.name">
                <Template>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach(string st in rt.values)
                        {
                            <li>
                                @st
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </Template>
            </RadzenDataGridColumn>
        }
    </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

Comment: You probably will find this helpful:  https://forum.radzen.com/t/radzen-grid-creating-and-filling-columns-dynamically/6957